# "while()" function?

Tags: c, while-loop

This program is supposed to convert degrees Fahrenheit into degrees Celsius:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    float fahrenheit, celsius;
    int max, min, step;

    max = 100;
    min = 0;
    step = 5;

    fahrenheit = 0.0;
    //celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0/9.0; DOESN'T WORK HERE

    printf("\n");
    printf("This program converts fahrenheit into celsius \n");

    while(fahrenheit <= max) {
        celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0/9.0; /* Works here */
        printf("%3.0f %6.2f\n", fahrenheit, celsius);
        fahrenheit = fahrenheit + step;
    }
}
```

As I noted in my source comments, when I try put the formula for celsius into the body of the `main()` function, I get `-17.8` for every single fahrenheit value. The output looks like this -

```
0 -17.78
5 -17.78
10 -17.78
15 -17.78
20 -17.78
25 -17.78
```

and so on and so on. However, when I put the celsius formula into the `while()` function, I get the correct celsius values for each fahrenheit value. It looks like this:

```
0 -17.78
5 -15.00
10 -12.22
15  -9.44
20  -6.67
```

Why does that happen?

Here's the code that doesn't work. It's identical to the code above, except for the location of the celsius formula. (At least, I think it is.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
//this program is supposed to convert fahrenheit into celsius 
int main() {
    float fahrenheit, celsius;
    int max, min, step;

    max = 100;
    min = 0;
    step = 5;

    fahrenheit = 0.0;
    celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0/9.0; 

    printf("\n");
    printf("This program converts fahrenheit into celsius \n");

    while(fahrenheit <= max) {
        printf("%3.0f %6.2f\n", fahrenheit, celsius);
        fahrenheit = fahrenheit + step;
    }
}
```

Comment: `while` is not a function; it's a keyword that specifies a particular kind of statement. The code in your question works correctly. We need to see the code that *doesn't* work.

Comment: @KeithThompson He provided code that doesn't work: The same code, but the conversion code is moved out of the loop.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Yes, he edited the question after my comment.

Comment: the code that does not work is because the calculation is only performed for one value of Fahrenheit,  Specifically when it is equal to 0.  My suggestion, given your comments and code, is to spend a bit of time learning the C language

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you set a value to a variable, the actual value is computed, and then stored to the variable. You do *not* store a formula for the variable, however. Thus, when you run

```
celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0/9.0;
```

*outside* of the `while` loop, it uses the current value of `fahrenheit` (which is 0.0), and calculates the value for `celsius`, which is -17.78.

*Inside* the `while` loop, although `fahrenheit` changes, `celsius` will not, because there are no statements inside of the `while` loop to actually change the value of the variable. This is why you have to move the statement into the `while` loop, to make sure that the `celsius` value updates every time the `fahrenheit` value changes.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO. You are coming to grips with one of the basic flow control statements present in every programming language.

Basically, any computer program is a sequence of instructions and you can envisage the computer executing them one at a time from the top to the bottom of the page.

Logically, that means every instruction gets executed only once, unless there's a way to tell the program to "go backwards" and do something again. That's what the `while` statement (it's not  a function) does. In english a while statement (usually called a `while loop`) does something like this

```
if a condition is true
    execute some instructions
    go back and check the condition and keep looping
else 
    continue after the loop
```

So, your main loop has a group of statements which are executed only once (every thing before the `while`).

Then the statements inside the while loop are repeated with `fahrenheit` taking on the a different value each time through the loop: 0, 5, 10, 15, ..., 95, 100. When you add 5 the last time, `fahrenheit` has the value 105, so the program leaves the loop and continues on (in this case, ending the `main()` function and exiting the program.

If you have the `celsius` calculation outside the loop, it only happens once. Then each time through the loop it prints out the value you calculated - even though `fahrenheit` is constantly changing.

When you move the calculation inside the `while` loop, `celsius` gets recalculated on each pass through the loop, using the new value of `fahrenheit` and thus producing a different results.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

That's because while is a loop that is used to repeat a block of code.

If you put `celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0/9.0; /* Works here */` outside the block of while it will iterate just once (and it's going to be when fahrenheit = 0.0), but if you put `celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0/9.0; /* Works here */` inside the block of while celsius will be changing his value as fahrenheit does, while the condition `fahrenheit <= max` is true.

Comment: What do you mean by `bucle`?

Comment: It means loop... I thought it could also be said bucle in English, I was wrong.

Comment: minor nit: The loop will still iterate over fahrenheit from 0 to 100, not just once, it just won't print a different result

Answer (score 2):

The code:

```
celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0/9.0;
```

assigns the variable `celsius` with `(fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0/9.0`

Where you call the code outside the while loop, fahrenheit is 0 so celsius becomes -17.78

If you put the code inside the while loop, it will reassign celsius each time the while block loops. Fahrenheit changes inside this loop so each time the while loop executes, both fahrenheit and celsius will be different if you reassign celsius with `celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0/9.0;` inside the while loop.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot expect the value of `fahrenheit` to change outside the loop as you are converting a single value:

```
(-32.0) * 5.0/9.0 = -17.8 (every time)
```

The only time the value with change is if you are changing the value of `fahrenheit` itself. Outside of the loop. That doesn't happen.

Additionally, comparing an `int` against a `float` is never a good idea. The reason being that a floating point number, stored in IEEE-754 Single Precision Floating Point Format is not an exact representation of the value provided for storage. (e.g 32.2 is not stored in floating point format as exactly 32.2) While you can make a relative comparison:

```
while(fahrenheit <= max)
```

It is better practice to do:

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < max; i+=5) {
    fahrenheit += (float)i;
    celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0/9.0;
...
```

You are changing `fahrenheit` here within the loop and you can then expect the value of `celsius` to change accordingly.

Regarding floating point comparison, you will want to read [**The Floating-Point Guide - What Every Programmer Should Know ...**](http://floating-point-gui.de/). The problem is you are not comparing what you think you are.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: C will cast `i` to a float anyway, in `(i - 32.0)`.

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of promotion and the standard, but being explicit for learning emphasis never hurts.

Comment: There's also no harm in comparing floating-point numbers to integers when the floating-point number represents an integer, because it can represent the number exactly.

Comment: You will want to read [**The Floating-Point Guide - What Every Programmer Should Know ...**](http://floating-point-gui.de/). The problem is you are not comparing what you think you are.

Comment: If you’re worried about strange results from casting, it would be better to just store everything as a `float` in the original program. Or I’d recommend a `double`, just because.

Comment: More importantly, this doesn't answer the OPs question as to why he gets the same value if the calculation is outside the loop.

Comment: Don't worry children, I'm sure you will point out the technical inaccuracies as you find them. Please do.

Comment: `float` is exact, `int` is exact.  Certain operations do not provide exactly the same mathematical result.  `7/3`, `7.0/3.0`